# Empty method just to call super

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Should you add an empty method just to call super?

I've seen this a lot and would like to know, is it just junk code or do I need to leave it?

Example: Should you add this into a custom UIViewController subclass?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: It will probably be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: @uchuugaka Even if that's the case, it hurts my eye. (Just like commented junk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely remove it.

If you don't implement those methods, the implementation of the superclass will be used, so there's no difference at all.

Comment: Could you quote/provide a source? In case the "the answer on SO had X up-votes isn't enough".

Comment: @LordZsolt this is object oriented programming. When you inherit from a class your are inheriting its behaviour, so overriding a method just to call the super implementation is redundant, and not necessary